# Java Homogenous or Heterogenous types

Tags: java, generics, collections, containers

I just started getting into Java a couple of weeks ago and i stumbled on a rather strange problem. Its about creating a Homogeneous or Heterogeneous collections in Java. So far I have created a generic BinaryTree class which can use every type i throw at it. So far just the basic one. 
But i was wondering how would one implement a Collection which can take ANY type inside (such as String,Double,Integer) all at the same time inside the same collection. As far as i know the collection should be of type Object. The problem i am facing is how would i implement that witohut having to repeat my BinaryTree class and just replacing the generic with object. Is it possible to make it all in one Collection that can take The same and different types of objects at the same time. 
For the objects , being diffrent types and all i guess i should override compareTo and i plan on comparing different objects based on their hash code. Comparing is irrelevant in this case since the main idea is to force the collection to take same and different types at the same time. 
I want to take ArrayList as an example, it can do exactly that.

```
ArrayList<Object> ObejctList = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Integer> IntList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
public class MyBinaryTree<T> {

    public void put(T t) { ... }

}
```

Then you can do

```
new BinaryTree<Integer>
```

T would be treated as an Object though.

You can be more specific using `MyBinaryTree<T extends Number>`

Overall, see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: Yea well that works fine , i am able to add objects of different types as well of the same type . But if i try to say T extends Comparable , then i can no longer use Object (that understandable) but what is the solution here ? To be able to compare as well

Comment: You can do if (myObject instanceof Comparable) to see if your object implements the Comparable interface. If yes, then you can cast (Comparable)myObject

Comment: Yea if my object is comparable i can but i cant do  this if i say extends Comparable: SimpleTree<Object> tree = new SimpleTree<Object>();

Answer (score 1):

1. Why not use a `TreeMap`?
2. If you want things to work like `ArrayList`, then why not just open and read the implementation of `ArrayList` and do the same?

Comment: I tried to no avail. And i wanted to implement my own structure not use prebuilt. I want to be able to compare the elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept more than 1 type in your Collection such as (String,Double,Integer) you need to find a common subclass.
For example for Double and Integer you could use:

```
Collection<T extends Number> or Collection<? extends Number>
```

but if you want to use `String` here then you are right you have to use `Object` like so:

```
Collection<T extends Object> or Collection<? extends Object>
```

Here you can read more about generics [Bounded type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

Comment: Thats cool , but it tricky when i want to compare different object i want to compare their hashCodes and when i am comparing same types i want to compare their values